# How much time does robots.txt remain in Google cache?

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

The old `robots.txt` alerts me with warning about locked URL. With the new one, the URL passes the tester in Google Webmaster. But when I resend the sitemap I get the same error!

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Google reads the robots.txt file every 24 plus hours since the last time it read your robots.txt. Using Google Search Console will use the last one it has. You will just have to wait. Do not try and hurry Google up. It will not be long before your updated robots.txt file can be seen and used.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an exact answer to your question but this may help you more: If I remember correctly I have successfully used a manual "Fetch as Google" at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch to force a refresh of `robots.txt`.

Comment: I have seen reports where that has not worked effectively. So now I wonder what the truth is.

Comment: I've also used the fetch facility in webmaster tools and it updated robots.txt in their cache almost instantly